# Select Query - Get the Records where the columns should not start with two patterns - SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having table Customer which has two columns "Name" and "Identity".

I want to get the rows where the column "Identity" does not start with following two patterns.

1. aa.sam.
2. bb.test.

The table looks like

```
S.no.    Name.      Identity
--------------------------------
 1      Asif Ali    aa.sam.diamond.star
 2      Daniel Sam. bb.test.diamond.star
 3      Rob Boucher bc.sam.gold.star
 4      Anil        aa.sam.diamond.star
 5      CCC         bb.test.gold.star
```

I expect to get the final Result should be following:

```
 S.no.    Name.      Identity
--------------------------------
 3      Rob Boucher bc.sam.gold.star
 4      Anil        aa.sam.diamond.star
```

please help someone to solve my problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you want to get the rows where the column "Identity" does not start with `aa.sam.` why should the 4th row come into your result?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you just need a couple of `not like` clauses.

```
select *
  from customer
 where identity not like 'aa.sam.%'
   and identity not like 'bb.test.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [regular expression](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=094bef9d42bed9c2951b4bce500b6925) like below also -

```
SELECT *
  FROM TEST
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(IDENTITY, '(aa.sam.|bb.test.)');
```

P.S. - There might be a better regexp for this but I am able to manage only this.